# How can the numerical values of Theano hidden layers be accessed efficiently, i.e. not eval()?

Tags: theano, autoencoder

Excuse me, is there any efficient way of extracting the numerical values of hidden layer in theano? I can do this work with .eval(), which is super slow.

The code is (based on modification of dA.py)

```
y = numpy.ndarray([n_train_batches*batch_size,n_hidden])
   for batch_index in xrange(n_train_batches*batch_size):
        input = train_set_x[batch_index]

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        newyeval = da.get_hidden_values(input)
        end_time1 = timeit.default_timer()
        newy = newyeval.eval()#da.get_hidden_values(input).eval(), I split here to test time
        end_time2 = timeit.default_timer()
        print 'get_hidden time: ', str(end_time1 - start_time)
        print 'eval() time: ', str(end_time2 - end_time1)
```

It turns out .eval() is super slow, is there anyway I can improve it? I try to write it with theano.function, but I failed. Here is my code

```
## method3: function
WW = T.fmatrix()
bb = T.fmatrix()
inputs = T.fmatrix()
# print '---->503', type(WW), type(bb)
WW = T.cast(WW, dtype = 'floatX')
bb = T.cast(bb, dtype = 'floatX')
## f = theano.function([input, WW, bb],T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(input, WW) + bb) ) 
output = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(inputs, WW) + bb)
inputArray = [inputs, WW, bb]
f = theano.function(inputArray, output) 


start_time = timeit.default_timer()
newyeval = da.get_hidden_values(input)
y[batch_index] = f(input, da.W.get_value(), da.b.get_value())# I also tried the following, neither works, with same error log
#y[batch_index] = f(input, da.W, da.b)
end_time = timeit.default_timer()
print 'eval2() time: ', str(end_time - start_time)
```

It doesn't work, the error log is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/dA_bo.py", line 598, in <module>
    n_hidden = int(sys.argv[5]),  corruption_level = float(sys.argv[6]) )
  File "src/dA_bo.py", line 513, in test_dA
    y[batch_index] = f(input, da.W, da.b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 534, in __call__
    allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 77, in filter
    'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: '
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "src/dA_bo.py:507"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')
```

So I have two questions here:

1. How to write the function code here?
2. Is there any efficient way to output the numerical values of hidden layers in theano?

Comment: Creating a theano function is the right way to do it and it should work if `eval` works. I am not entirely sure how `eval` works internally, but it compiles the function *at least* once and is mostly for debugging purposes. The error you have is due to the fact that you are probably passing shared variables to your function. Try `y[batch_index] = f(input, da.W.get_value(), da.b.get_value())` instead, and see if it works. If it does, then set about using those shared value expressions in the function - it is weird to pass their values as an argument.

Comment: @eickenberg Thanks for your answer! However, da.W.get_value(), da.b.get_value() seem not work. Do you know where might be the problem? Thx a lot!

Comment: Well, it looks that they are not actually shared variables but tensor variables. Then `get_value` cannot work. I thought they were shared variables. I also said not to use that but to incorporate the variables in the function expression. I can't help any more without a *fully copy and pasteable example* reproducing the error.